# Animating opening/closing of table columns in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-animate

How can I animate the opening/closing of table columns in jQuery?

I currently have this piece of code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".togglebutton").click(function(e){
        if (cost_visible) {
            $(".numbers").animate({width: 80}, 1500);
            $(".costs").animate({width: 0}, 1500);

        } else {
            $(".numbers").animate({width: 0}, 1500);
            $(".costs").animate({width: 60}, 1500);
        }
    });
});
```

and my HTML containing standard TABLE/TR/TH/TD tags with the TH and TD tags carrying the class names used to identify what has to be opened or closed.

The problem seems to be that after jQuery touches the table, the affected cells suddenly feel the need to stack on top of eachother instead of remaining neatly in a row.

I assume this has to do with jQuery being only able to animate "block" elements, not elements that are displayed "table-like". So can I make a table out of block elements? Or is there another way to animate table-like elements? I've found [this](http://www.tino.nl/index.php/2009/08/05/table-animations-in-jquery/) suggested solution, but it seems like a hassle to encase all your table elements into DIV's just for the animation...

Comment: Do you've got a test page we can use?

Comment: I didn't, but I made one: http://www.antiflu.dds.nl/animatetable/ . I also already found a way to solve the problem, but you can play with it if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some study, I've found that...

- The problem is indeed caused by the TH and TD items being set by jQuery to "display: block" items for animation. There is as of yet no way to make jQuery behave differently.
- Enclosing the TH and TD items in DIV tags does not work, some Google searching turns up the suggestion that [HTML becomes invalid](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/93ea22a9c2372f7c) when using DIV tags within a TABLE structure.
- Enclosing the **content** of TH and TD items in DIV tags does not work, the content starts to float after animation and does not stay within the TH and TD items.
- [The same article](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/93ea22a9c2372f7c) reveals that animating the opening closing of table **rows** is possible using TBODY sections within the table.

I succeeded in what I wanted though, and here's how:

- I cut the table into several sub-tables consisting of the column groups I want to show and hide
- I enclosed these sub-tables in DIV tags and [floated](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction09.htm) them next to each other.
- I used jQuery to show/hide these DIV's.

I hope that this helps anybody, and if a more elegant solution is found, please leave a message.

Comment: Ugh, almost a year later, and this bug has not been fixed. Thanks for the idea on how to work around it though.

Comment: A tricky thing about this workaround is that the table row heights can easily get out of sync. I solved that by drawing the table with visibility: none, run a jQuery loop to sync the heights to the first column and then showing the table. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

While it's not the same effect, the fadeIn() and fadeOut() jQuery methods work properly on tables. The show() and hide() methods (without animation) also work.

Comment: Thanks! Almost an anniversary present for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Happy anniversary.**

It is weird how January seems to be table sliding effects time. I suppose its the to ease back into work hey :) But I managed to create a side ways columns collapsing effect.

```
$(table).each(...
    var columnNo = $(cell).index();
    $('div', cell).animate({ width: '0px' }, 'slow');
    $(cell).closest("table")
        .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (columnNo + 1) + ") div")
        .animate({ width: '0px' }, 'slow')
...)
```

Basically this is a workaround using divs. I select each `cell` "th" and then find every other cell in that column. And progressivlu it reduces each div pixel size using animation. The table will recalculate as per HTML specification, because the occupying space is changing. Once its complete you can hide the column to make them "disappear"

Script to wrap everything in a div, like on page load, or after clicking a button. You can remove the div after animation is complete too, in case it messes with your form submit or other scripts.

```
 $('#Stupid_RadGrid th').each(function () {
          $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>"); 
 });
 $('#Stupid_RadGrid td').each(function () {
         $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>");
 });
```

I'll update once I got it working both ways.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using a div overlay. The animation will be done on this div overlay, while the table element stay untouched.

Here the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cbcr9yh9/).

**JS:**

```
$("div").css("width", $("table").width() + 10); //10px of margin
$("div").css("height", $("table").height() + 10); //10px of margin

$("#show").click( function(){
    $("div").animate({
        left: $("div").width()
    }, function (){
    $("div").hide();
    });
});

$("#hide").click( function() {
    $("div").show( "fast", function (){
        $("div").animate({ left: "0px" });
    });
});
```