# How to perform sliding animation on a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with and many (dynamic number) rows, and the screen visible region is 4 rows. Each table cell contains an image. I need to slide this table to show the 5th and more rows, and I want the animation effects when sliding it.

I have tried `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`, but I don't know what exactly I should animate.
My table generation code is:

```
$().ready(function() {
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
    for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        $tr.append($('<td><div><img src="pic' + (j + i * 7) + '.png" /></div></td>'));
    }
    $('tbody').append($tr);
}
});
```

How can I really do an animation effect or sliding rows?

Comment: I think it's better to use div's, it's really hard to make jQuery effects work on a table

Comment: I also think you can divide your content in different div section and place in one div and animate.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2380968/901048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t use the `slide` animations on `table`s because it´s not possible to set the height of rows to 0.

See [Animating opening/closing of table columns in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071420/animating-opening-closing-of-table-columns-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr/>');
    for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        $tr.append($('<td><div><img src="pic' + (j + i * 7) + '.png" /></div></td>'));
    }
    $tr.hide().appendTo($('tbody')).slideDown();
}
});
```

**UPDATE**

This jsFiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/A4fn6/